# In JSONata How to print date from todays date+60 calendar days

Tags: jsonata

For eg:

- if today's date is 03/39/2024, it should print after 60 days -05/28/2024

Code to get today's date:

```
$fromMillis($toMillis($now()), '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')
```

But how to print for 60 calendar days in jsonata? Can anyone please help?`

Comment: Try now() + (days * 86400000msesc | 86400sescs)        : -)